# "Women are gateway to hell" . From which scripture this quote come from?

Tags: scripture, women

There is old saying in hindi "स्त्री नर्क का द्वार है" which translates to "Women are gateways to hell".

From which scripture this quote comes from ?

Comment: shrimad bhagwat

Comment: @Harsh Please give the verse number.

Comment: I heard it from hrishikesh brahmachari ji disciple of govardhan peethadhishwar

Comment: This question is answered. Why hasn't the questioner marked it as answered yet?

Comment: the real meaning is that 'lust' is gateway to hell, not all women.

Comment: @SanatanaDhara I will after few days . I am waiting for more answers if there are any . I will mark the best one as answered. I always do like this .Most of my questions are marked as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ŚB 3.31.39**

> > सङ्गं न कुर्यात्प्रमदासु जातु
> > योगस्य पारं परमारुरुक्षु: ।
> > मत्सेवया प्रतिलब्धात्मलाभो
> > वदन्ति या निरयद्वारमस्य ॥ ३९ ॥
> > One who **aspires to reach the culmination of yoga** and has realized his self by rendering service unto Me should never associate with an **attractive woman**, for such a woman is declared in the scripture to be the gateway to hell for the advancing devotee.

This thing was even said by sankaracharya ji mahabhaag and many other saints.

Note:- This verse can be grossly misunderstood.Here it is said the **person who wants to reach at climax of yoga** should avoid an **attractive woman**.We can easily conclude that it is spoken withrespect to **kaam(lust)**.

So we should not take this verse literally and consider woman(which also includes mother,sister,wife etc) to be gateway of hell

Comment: It should be noted that (in the successive verses) the concept is reversed and applied to the woman. I.e., the woman (who wants liberation) should understand death to be the form of the husband.

Comment: Has this been said by Krishna ?